# Redis: Set time = Get time. Why?

Tags: mongodb, performance, python-2.7, redis, ibm-cloud

*Short: Redis set time = get time (strange)*

I did some tests just insert 30000 records and than receive them 30000 times (Redis).

```
     def redis_set(data):
      for k, v in data.iteritems():
          redis_conn.set(k, v)

    def redis_get(data):
      for k in data.iterkeys():
         val = redis_conn.get(k)

    def do_tests(num, tests):
      # setup dict with key/values to retrieve
      data = {'key' + str(i): 'val' + str(i)*100 for i in range(num)}
      # run tests
     for test in tests:
         start = time.time()
         print "Starting test .. %s" % (test.__name__)
         test(data)
         elapsed = time.time() - start
         print "%s: %d ops in %.2f seconds : %.1f ops/sec" % (test.__name__, num, elapsed, num / elapsed)

     tests = [redis_set, redis_get]
     do_tests(30000, tests)
```

**Results**

**Redis**:

*redis_set: 30000 ops in 106.21 seconds : 282.4 ops/sec*

*redis_get: 30000 ops in 94.94 seconds : 316.0 ops/sec*

It is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nothing goes wrong.**

Since Redis is single-threaded, there's no lock penalty for read and write operations. Both `GET` and `SET` are several memory operations, and both are very fast.

According to your benchmark, `SET` is a little slower than `GET`. That's also reasonable, since `SET` operation needs to allocate memory for newly added item, and memory allocation costs more than other memory operations.

On the other hand, Mongodb's read operation is much faster than write operation. Because it does lots of optimizations for read operations, such as cache. And the intention lock that Mongodb used is much more friendly to read operations, i.e. multiple readers can read data from a single slot at the same time, while writers are exclusive.

Comment: MongoDb was very fast because find() returns only cursor, not data - sorry. I changed the question - removed MongoDB tests.